# Parallelogram inside of a triangle dependencies

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

APMH is a parallelogram inside the triangle ABC. It has a perimeter of 18cm. So my question is **could MP divide AB by 2 equal parts AP and PB**???

Comment: Hint: If $P$ is the midpoint of $AB$ then $M$ and $H$ are the midpoints of the sides they are on. (Do you know why?)

Comment: Yes, but it is not given that `P` is the midpoint of AB. Here's the entire problem: I need to find the sides of the parallelogram by what's given in the above question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment by Ethan Bolker is a good hint to the original question.

($AP=PB\Rightarrow AP=6,AH=\frac 12AC=4\Rightarrow \text{perimeter}=20$, a contradiction.)

To find the sides of the parallelogram, let $AP=HM=a,AH=PM=b$. Then, we have
$$2a+2b=18\Rightarrow b=9-a.$$
Here, note that we have
$$CH=8-b=8-(9-a)=a-1,\ \ PB=12-a.$$

Since $\triangle{CHM}$ and $\triangle{MPB}$ are similar, we have
$$CH:MP=HM:PB,$$
i.e.
$$a-1:9-a=a:12-a.$$
Solving this gives you $AP=a=3,AH=b=6$.

Comment: Or directly: $AP=3$, $PB=12-3=9$, so $AP\neq PB$.

Comment: @user26486: Of course, you are right. But to know $AP\not=PB$, you don't need to find $AP$.